# Wrong Result of Add Variadic Function

Tags: c++

I have written the following variadic add function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

int Add(int arg_a, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, arg_a);

    int itSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arg_a; i++)
    {
        itSum += va_arg(va, int);
    }
    va_end(va);

    return itSum;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    int Sum = Add(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8);
    std::cout << "Final: " << Sum << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

But when I run the above program, it shows me the wrong result of 7. What is wrong with this code?

Result:

```
Final: 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument is the number of args in your code.

If I got it correctly you want to add all those numbers you are passing. They are `7` in total. So you should pass `7` as your first argument.

Make it:

```
int Sum = Add(7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8);
```

and it will work fine.

The reason for the result you get is that you passed `2` as your first arg and your function receives it in `arg_a` and runs loop that many times.

So you only get sum of first two numbers after `2` i.e. `3+4`.

Answer (score 0):

the arguments that you specify before ... are the arguments you must give to the function when calling otherwise it will give an error.

and those arguments before ... will take the value serially from the function call.

`int Add(int arg_a, ...)`   means that whatever your are passing in the function call the first value will be stored in arg_a
inorder to traverse the whole array you need to give the size of the array in the first of the arguments
for example:

```
Add(2,3,5,6) here arg_a is 2 and the function will return 3+5=8
Add(3,3,5,6) here arg_a is 3 and the function will return 3+5+6=14
```